# Divergence of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, improper-integrals

I found in web the following problem:

> Let $f,g$ be continuous non-negative decreasing functions on $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ such that $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx\to\infty, \int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx\to\infty$$. Define the function $h$ by $h(x)=\min \{f(x),g(x)\},\forall x\in\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$. Prove or disprove that $$\int_0^\infty h(x)\,dx$$ also diverges.

I bet the statement is true, so I attempt to prove it. Firstly, since $h$ is also continuous, non-negative and decreasing, we know that the statement is equivalent to say

> Let $f,g$ be continuous non-negative decreasing functions defined on $\mathbb N$, show that
>   $$(\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)\to\infty\land \sum_{k=0}^\infty g(x)\to\infty )\implies \sum_{k=0}^\infty \min\{f(k),g(k)\}\to\infty $$

Now, if one has assumed the limits
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/\min\{f(n),g(n)\}, \lim_{n\to\infty} \min\{f(n),g(n)\}/g(n), \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/g(n)$$ all exist, I think I could give a proof.

Let $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/\min\{f(n),g(n)\}=L_1, \lim_{n\to\infty} \min\{f(n),g(n)\}/g(n)=L_2, \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/g(n)=L$$. We know that any of $L_1,L_2, L$ is nonnegative. Since $L_1L_2=L$, if $L>0$, then we are done by the limit comparison test. If $L=0$, then in the long run $\min\{f(x),g(x)\}\sim f(x)$, we are done as well.

However, I could hardly think of an approach if the assumption is not made. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. Then take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $$g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in (0, 1]\\
\frac{1}{x} & x \in [1, \infty)
\end{cases}$$.

Comment: My apologies. When I said $\mathbb R_+$ I really meant $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$.

Comment: @Verbe how so? Shifting $\frac{1}{x^2}$ to get rid of the singularity will result in it being integrable on $(0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt to prove (it's only a rought idea)

let define

$$M(x)=max(f,g)$$
and
$$I_1(x)=\frac{M(x)+h(x)}{2}$$
thus by comparison $I_1(x)$ diverges

then define

$$I_k(x)=\frac{I_{k-1}(x)+h(x)}{2}$$

thus by induction $I_k(x)$ diverges

as $$I_k(x) \rightarrow h(x)$$

$h(x)$ also diverges $\square$?

Comment: But could induction imply the case when taking limit?

Comment: @BAI I'm not sure, hope someone else will give some hints on that.